# vmware 12 not detecting usb

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

[image]I installed vmware workstation 14 to test some apps on windows. However I uninstalled it and reinstalled v12 because was not detecting the usb device on VM > Removable devices.

Now this is detecting it however the usb is not showing up under Computer on Windows 7(virtual machine)

Tried the solution to share this usb as shared folder and it worked but I need to show up like a regular usb plug in device to mirror de environment I have on another box and troubleshoot something else.

Checked also Windows Services to make sure VMware USB Arbitration Service is running but the service is not there.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: You are sure the USB device is functioning?

Comment: I am sure since is detecting it on the guest machine and when I configure it as a shared folder I can read it.

Comment: When I ask if it is functioning I am asking if the host machines detects and is able to mount it.

Comment: Yes, is able to mount it 100%